# References not updating from Jabref

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, jabref

I created a document with TeXstudio and Jabref. Everything was going smooth until I wanted to make some additional changes in a couple of references. Per usual I made changes in Jabref, compiled both Jabref and .tex twice. While the changes show in my .bib file, the changes don't translate to the .tex data. The references in .tex remain unchanged. I already tried the following after reading some blog posts:

1. Compiled at least twice --> no change
2. Deleting all temporary files and recompiling .tex --> Error: Undefinde citing
3. Checked for dublicate .bib data,  --> non found

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  While I've never used Jabref, I believe that only creates the `.bib` file.  This usually has to be compiled into a `.bbl` file and that requires a separate step.  If your original processing included running bibtex, you will need to run that again.  Check to see if you have a `.bbl` file, and if you do, either rename or delete it, then rerun LaTeX.  That will either result in an error, or force the rerunning of the step that created the `.bbl file.

Comment: Thank you Barbara, you were right. But after I delete and compile the .bbl data won't be created again unless I compile the Bibtex using an extra step via Tools --> Command --> Bbitex. This solved the problem. But I wonder why it doesn't work like before =)

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't use Jabref, I believe it only creates a `.bib` file.

LaTeX doesn't read a `.bib` file; it requires a `.bbl` file.  So whenever new items are added to the bibliography (by whatever means), bibtex (or its equivalent) must be rerun to update the `.bbl` file.

There are methods for defining a multi-step procedure that can include a  bibtex step, but I won't go into that since this information can be found elsewhere (and since I usually do this as a manual step, I don't want to recommend anything in particular).